# How to reduce time of execution for javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

Below is my code which is taking time in the `for` loop to extract data from one object and filling another object. Is there any way to reduce the time of execution? I have tried a `while` loop but it is not helping that much. Kindly help

```
function SetGridWithData(result) {
    if (!result) {
        return;
    }
    CtrlBillableItem_SearhedBillableItems = result
    var boxOfJson = [];
    var j = 100;
    if (result.length >= 100) {
        if (PagingLastRecNum == 0) {

            btnPrevious.style.display = 'none';
            for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                boxOfJson.push(result[i]);
            }
        } else {
            btnPrevious.style.display = 'inline';
            var intializer = (j * PagingLastRecNum) + PagingLastRecNum;
            var limiter = intializer + 99;
            for (var i = intializer; i < limiter; i++) {
                boxOfJson.push(result[i]);
            }
        }

    } else {
        btnPrevious.style.display = 'none';
        btnNext.style.display = 'none';

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            boxOfJson.push(result[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to implement paging which is done, but 100 data per page first it will check page no 0 if it is then loop one and if other than 0 than else case.

Comment: You could try [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to take a subsection of your array in one go, rather than pushing into a new array, which may involve reallocation and expansion of that array as it grows. But I doubt even that would be slow for 100 elements.

Comment: Also since you're using `i < limiter` not `i <= limiter` you probably want to add the 100 again, not 99.

Comment: sorry the last comment i haven't get can you explain me a bit more is there any mistake i mean it will fetch next 100 always right?

Comment: thanks it wont take 100th data i got it thanks a lot

Comment: Go with slice, as @Rup pointed out. As a note: Preallocating arrays via `new Array(length)` is always faster than dynamic expanding them in a loop with known bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You could try caching `result.length` at the beginning of your function (following the if check at the beginning)..

```
   function SetGridWithData(result) {
            if (!result) { return; }
            var resultLength = result.length;
            CtrlBillableItem_SearhedBillableItems = result
            var boxOfJson = [];
            var j = 100;
            if (resultLength >= 100) {
                if (PagingLastRecNum == 0) {

                    btnPrevious.style.display = 'none';
                    for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                        boxOfJson.push(result[i]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    btnPrevious.style.display = 'inline';
                    var intializer = (j * PagingLastRecNum) + PagingLastRecNum;
                    var limiter = intializer + 99;
                    for (var i = intializer; i < limiter; i++) {
                        boxOfJson.push(result[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                btnPrevious.style.display = 'none';
                btnNext.style.display = 'none';

                for (var i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
                    boxOfJson.push(result[i]);
                }

            }
}
```